# Rome 2 Disc not recognised

Tags: windows-7, dvd

My son got me Rome 2 (3 disc retail version)and I just tried to install it and my computer does not recognise the disc has been put in. I put in other discs in the drive and it's fine. I put the Rome 2 disc in other computers and it works. I also changed the drive and cable, same problem.  I checked the region on drives and they are the same on all computers.

Operating System: Windows 7

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: It may be because the DVD-ROM drive you have supports only DVD+R or DVD-R and the discs are actually the opposite. Don't really remember what the deal was with them, but definitely they're not compatible somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The drive supports both formats.
My device manager names the drive as "hl-dt-st dvd-ram gsa -h55n ata" which is an LG drive.

Comment: @user251181: Have you tried leaving the disk in there for several minutes? It may use some copy protection system that your DVD drive is having trouble coping with. Also, you could try updating the firmware: http://www.lg.com/uk/support-product/lg-GSA-H55N

Comment: I am attempting again but will leave in for a longer time as per your suggestion. Will not be able to reboot computer until tomorrow so will update firmware tomorrow, thanks for the link. If both suggestions fail will let you know tomorrow, thanks James for the good ideas.

Comment: Left the DVD in longer and also updated firmware. Still not recognising the DVD is there.

Comment: @user251181: Did you try powering the computer on and off again after updating the DVD drive firmware? It could also be worth trying a lens cleaning CD.

Comment: @James Yes I did turn the computer off then on. I gave the game to my son and it worked on his laptop so he will keep that set of discs. I have decided to get a bluray/DVD combo drive then will get my own set of discs and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to send it back. Try it on another machine though to confirm if it is your computer or the disc.

If the DVD is not needed to run the game (only for installation) then take an image from it  (you will need to do this on another machine obviously).

Or, if you can find a trusted source, torrent it! You have paid for it.

Comment: As far as I know the disc is fine on other computers, it's just mine that it doesn't work on. I am fairly confident my drive is okay since other disks work okay.
If James suggestions fail I will attempt to take an image(nice idea) and see if that works. Will try tomorrow, thanks Dave.

Comment: Have not been able to image DVD, when I have managed that I will let you know of the result.